# Bash sort, I don't know how to sort the same line, and choose the older

Tags: bash

I have some question, I don't find and I don't know how implement good sort in my script. I want to sort some of input string, to show me redundancy (some repetition), and from this, return the line of biggest repetition, and if I have more the same repetition for example

input :

```
qwe1
qwe1
wer2
wer2
wer4
```

output: // What I want

```
2 qwe1 
input:
asd1
asd1
asd1
asd2
asd2
asd2
asd3
asd3
asd3
output: // What i want
3 asd1  // If I have a the same name return id of alphabeticall first 

#!/bin/bash
sort -n|uniq -c -i | sort -dr | head -n1
```

I tried some of other arguments of sort, but I didn't find a solution.

Sorry for my english, please someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
 sort | uniq -c | sort -nrs | head -1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sort | uniq -c | sort -k1nr -k2 | head -1
```

where `-k1nr` means sort on the first column numerically and reverse (high to low)
and `-k2` means, where first keys are equal, sort by column2 (alphabetically)

Answer (score 0):

```
sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{if(a&&a!=$1){print a,b;exit;}a=$1;b=$2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can all be done in one single awk command. Consider this:

```
awk '{freq[$0]++;} END {for (var in freq)
{if (freq[var]>max || (freq[var]==max && var < item)) 
{max=freq[var]; item=var} } print max, item; }' file.txt
```